# SSRS report is not taking multiple values, Can I know how to fix this problem ,I am using the Snowflake code

Tags: reporting-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have used **IN** in the code to take multiple values.

`WHERE (I8AA IN ('0', '1', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8') AND (B2A0 IN '"+Parameters!BillC.Value+"'));`

I have set up this way in the report, in the dataset, under parameter expression.
[image]

I have used the option multiple values as the below in the under the parameter
[image]

Please let me know where can I fix the problem.
The parameter values datatype is **Varchar**.

Comment: This has everything to do with SSRS and nothing to do with Snowflake.

Comment: Perhaps you can get SSRS to show you the code string it generates and share it here, or, if an error is produced, share the error message?

Comment: What error message are you getting? Normally for the query you would have to use `IN (@Bill)`